# JPA and the last object added

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I use EclipseLink JPA and for my work. And use GenerationType.TABLE.

When I create a new object using persist, how do I retrieve the id field of the created object.

Example:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();

Student student = new Student();

student.setName("Joe");

em.persist(student);
em.flush();
em.getTransaction().commit();

Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Student e");
List<Student> list = (List<Student>) query.getResultList();
System.out.println(list);

em.close();
emf.close();
```

So I see all the students, but how do you know which one is the one that I created in an environment where there is competition.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume question is about generated id, because otherwise you of course already have id in your hands.

Generated id can be found after flush operation with following:

1. calling `student.nameOfTheGetterForID`
2. via [PersistenceUnitUtil.getIdentifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceUnitUtil.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.Object%29):

   //cast result to the type of id
   em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(student);